# phonegap how to use social share plugin?

Tags: jquery, cordova, twitter, phonegap-plugins, socialshare

i am using this plugin 
 [SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)

i have used this code

```
<!-- unlike most apps Twitter doesn't like it when you use an array to pass multiple files as the second param -->
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter('Message via Twitter')">message via Twitter</button>
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter('Message and link via Twitter', null /* img */, 'http://www.x-services.nl')">msg and link via Twitter</button>
```

i have **twitter app** in my mobile It is working fine. i don't have **twitter app** in my mobile it is not working. can you help me? suppose if i haven't twitter app in mobile.automatically  goto **Web browser** share my content

Comment: Does the plugin documentation tells anything about needing applications to be installed on the phone?

Comment: i think no @Cristik . that documentation only twitter,facebook share content ios and android phone only

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue, and found a solution.

Actually, you can use 5 parameters for shareByTwitter function, 
the last one is onError function, which is launched when Twitter App is not installed. 
So we added call to Twitter sharing page in this function, now it works fine :

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter(
    /* message */ 'Message via Twitter', 
    /* img */ null, 
    /* url */ yourPermalink , 
    /* function onSuccess */ function() {
        console.log('share ok');
    }, 
    /* function onError */ function(errormsg){
        // when Twitter app is not installed : directly open twitter on web browser
        window.open('https://twitter.com/share?url=' + yourPermaLink, '_blank');
    }
)
```

(see https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#sharing-directly-to)

You could also choose to redirect the user to Twitter application on PlayStore or AppStore, using *market://* or something like that.

Hope it can help